# Android set Text position permanently does not work

Tags: android, textview

Hello Stack community,

I want to change the position of text view.

I have tried several ways, but for all of them, the view position is set back to original position.

The ways I tried,

```
    // 1. way
    someText.setX(newPositionX);
    someText.setY(newPositionY);

    // 2.way
    someText.x(newPositionX).y(newPositionY).setDuration(0).start();

    // 3.way
   someText.animate().x(newPositionX).y(newPositionY).setDuration(0).start();

    //4.way
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimatorX= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(someText, "translationX", oldPositionX, newPositionX);
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimatorY= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(someText, "translationY", oldPositionY, newPositionY);
    objectAnimatorX.setDuration(0);
    objectAnimatorX.start();
    objectAnimatorY.setDuration(0);
    objectAnimatorY.start();

    // 5.way
    ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(someText, "x", newPositionX);
    ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(someText, "y", newPositionY);
    AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
    animSetXY.playTogether(animX, animY);
    animSetXY.start();
```

For all these ways, it is reset to original place.

However when I use animate function in onTouch event eg. `someText.animate().x(newPositionX).y(newPositionY).setDuration(0).start();`

it does not set to original coordinate, the change is permanent. This what i want but I want to do this, without touch event, namely some other part of the code which uses some other events.

My questions are

1. Why the change is permanent when I use onTouch event while it is temporary when I dont use onTouch event?
2. How can I achieve to set Text position permanently?

Lastly my xml is like this for textView

```
    `<TextView
    android:id="@+id/latinBigTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"

    android:background="@drawable/border_text"
    android:text="Initial text " />`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I have fixed. I have not still got the best results but it updates permanently. Most probably because of my calculations but for now it seems that the position update remains. I have used following code:

```
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, deltaX, 0, deltaY);
    anim.setDuration(0);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    anim.setFillEnabled(true);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            int l = newPosX;
            int t = newPosY;
            int r = SomeText.getWidth() + newPosX;
            int b = SomeText.getHeight() + newPosY;
            latinText.layout(l, t, r, b);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
        {
        }
    });
    latinText.startAnimation(anim);
```

Where SomeText is the textView which I want to move permanently and dynamically. DeltaX and DeltaY is the amount of pixel that I want to move. 
(l, r, t, b) means (left, top, right, bottom) of the view.

I hope it helps other people who have faced the same problem.

However I have still no answer for my first question. If anyone knows and tells, I would be very appreciated.